# I want to add more words in the array and increase score after each successful guess. How to do it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

It is basically a word-guessing game. I want to add more words and increase the score after each guess. I would also like to add a timer of 30 seconds, the player has to answer within the time limit. As you can see currently I have stored alphabets in an array and its correct answer. I am willing to add a complete set of words and compare and answers to each word. How can I achieve this? Is there anyone who can help me?

```
    private int presCounter = 0;
    private int score = 0;
    private int maxPresCounter = 4;
    private String[] keys = {"R", "I", "B", "D", "X"};
    private String textAnswer = "BIRD";
    TextView textScreen, textQuestion, textTitle;
    Animation smallbigforth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    smallbigforth = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.smallbigforth);

    keys = shuffleArray(keys);

    for (String key : keys) {
        addView(((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutParent)), key, ((EditText) 
    findViewById(R.id.editText)));
    }

    maxPresCounter = 4;
}


private void doValidate() {
    presCounter = 0;

    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.layoutParent);

    if(editText.getText().toString().equals(textAnswer)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BossAct.class);
        startActivity(a);

        editText.setText("");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        editText.setText("");
    }

    keys = shuffleArray(keys);
    linearLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (String key : keys) {
        addView(linearLayout, key, editText);
    }

}
```

Any extra suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Comment: add more words, you want to set it early or random?

Comment: Random, please help me, my friend.

Comment: textAnswers and key, did you call them from database ?

Comment: No, it's simple array

Comment: More words or letters?

Comment: If I give you the GitHub link can you fix this for me?

Comment: I want to store complete words instead of letters and also the answers. Are you Palestinian brother?

Comment: Are you helping me, bro?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new method that clears and adds new letters in your array. Call the method on each completion.

I think you should provide more code here. The app seems quite simple but what is your approach? What exact do you want your app to do? Is there any reason why you are not creating a class to store your question sets?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how familiar you are with Kotlin, but it should be straight forward to convert it to Java.

There are many ways to do what you are trying to do. One simple way is following these steps:

1- Have you array of words (Answers)
EX:

```
private val words = listOf(
       "BIRD",
       "CAT",
       "HOUSE" ...
   )
```

2- Have a function that generated X number of random letters that you can add to your word.
EX: This> getRandomString(3) would return a string of 3 random letters Ex: "BCG"

```
    fun getRandomString(length: Int) : String {
        val allowedChars = ('A'..'Z')
        return (1..length)
            .map { allowedChars.random() }
            .joinToString("")
    }
```

3- Have a function that returns a word at a specific position from your list of words (ANSWERS) to make things easier.
EX:

```
    fun getWordFromList(position: Int): String {
        return words[position]
    }
```

4- Now you can do something like the following: get X number of extra letters, add/concatenate that to whatever word you want, you can then convert that String no an array and use the shuffleArray function that you already have to shuffle that.
EX:

```
        //Get 3 extra letters as a String
        val extraLetters = getRandomString(3)

        //Concatenate extra letters to your word (In this case position 0 is BIRD)
        val wordAndExtraLetters = getWordFromList(0).plus(extraLetters)
        
        //Convert to Array
        val newArray = wordAndExtraLetters.toCharArray()

        //Shuffle
        val shuffledWordAndExtraLetters = shuffleArray(newArray)
```

4- Now you can get your users response, compare to the word in your list of words and increase the score if it is correct:

```
        //GET USER RESPONSE...
        if(response == getWordFromList(0))
            score ++
```

Sorry I did not have time to test this. This logic can definitely still be improved. Hopefully it helps you a bit

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] answers = {
        "BIRD",
        "HAMSTER",
        "BEAR",
    };

    //How many random extra letters to put in the answer.
    int extraLetters = 2;

    Random rand = new Random();

    for(int i=0; i < answers.length; ++i) {
        //Convert string of answer to a list of characters.
        List<Character> randLetters = new ArrayList<Character>(answers[i].length() + extraLetters);
        for(int n=0; n<answers[i].length(); ++n) {
            randLetters.add(answers[i].charAt(n));
        }

    //Generate N random letters for each answer.
    for(int l=0; l < extraLetters; ++l) {
        final char letter = (char)(65 + rand.nextInt(25));
        randLetters.add(letter);
    }

    //Shuffle the list.
    Collections.shuffle(randLetters);

    //DEBUG
    System.out.println("ANSWER: " + answers[i] + " SHUFFLE LETTERS: " + randLetters);

    //Output: (Formatted the clarity)
    //ANSWER: BIRD     SHUFFLE LETTERS: [Y, D, R, I, W, B]
    //ANSWER: HAMSTER  SHUFFLE LETTERS: [Y, M, A, M, E, T, H, R, S]
    //ANSWER: BEAR     SHUFFLE LETTERS: [E, S, B, O, A, R]
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a button, I want on button click it should check the aswer

Comment: Then make it so. Get the text from `EditText` than compare with the answer.